# Error: Error serializing `propertiesForSale` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/". Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying to fetch data from the Zillow API through RapidApi. I am new to NextJS.

Here is the code from my index.js:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const propertyForSale = await fetchApi(`${baseUrl}/propertyExtendedSearch/list?location=Texas&purpose=for-sale&hitsPerPage=6`)
  const propertyForRent = await fetchApi(`${baseUrl}/propertyExtendedSearch/list?location=Texas&purpose=for-rent&hitsPerPage=6`)

  return {
    props: {
      propertiesForSale: propertyForSale?.hits,
      propertiesForRent: propertyForRent?.hits,
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code from my fetchApi.js:

```
export const baseUrl = 'https://zillow-com1.p.rapidapi.com'

export const fetchApi = async (url) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get ((url), {
        headers: {
            'x-rapidapi-host': 'zillow-com1.p.rapidapi.com',
            'x-rapidapi-key': '8e2e11ca6dmsh77a061b9b854a4ep1762d7jsne6e273637c9f'
        }
    })
    return data;
}
```

Comment: What does the API call return?

Answer (score 1):

I ran through your request through postman  and it does not return any results

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://zillow-com1.p.rapidapi.com/propertyExtendedSearch/list?location=Texas%26purpose=for-sale%26hitsPerPage=6' \
--header 'x-rapidapi-host: zillow-com1.p.rapidapi.com' \
--header 'x-rapidapi-key: 8e2e11ca6dmsh77a061b9b854a4ep1762d7jsne6e273637c9f'
```

It returns

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "statusMessage": "Endpoint no found! Check your query URL and parameters!"
}
```

Check your get request outside of code and re-post the question. For stability of the solution and if the API offers the `status` node consistently you should check for *success* before proceeding to access other values.

Comment: Thank you. This pointed me in the right direction and I was able to google myself the rest of the way out using a different API.

Comment: Excellent, if this or another answer helped you - Please mark the answer as accepted. I would also ask that you revoke/re-generate the API key

Comment: Please remove the API key from your snippet, it is not safe.

Answer (score 0):

//change the ?. hit to ?.data just the way i did it below

export async function getStaticProps() {
const propertyForSale = await fetchApi(`${baseUrl}/propertyExtendedSearch/list?location=Texas&purpose=for-sale&hitsPerPage=6`)
const propertyForRent = await fetchApi(`${baseUrl}/propertyExtendedSearch/list?location=Texas&purpose=for-rent&hitsPerPage=6`)

return {
props: {
propertiesForSale: propertyForSale?.data,
propertiesForRent: propertyForRent?.data,
}
}
}

Comment: please fix the formatting.